# Package list Error, cannot open software updater or Package list

Tags: apt

I am getting an error in the Title Bar above

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I have removed Spotify, still the error persists. I cannot access Software Updater or Package Manager.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 on 64-bit laptop. I am new to Ubuntu, Please help.